# How to load plugins in the new tab in mac vim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, vim, macvim

I'm using macvim to code rails project.

I used some plugins, which is specific to rails(like vim-rails) and will be loaded only in a rails' app folder.

After I entered a rails's folder, I run mvim and everything goes fine.

However, when I use command + T to open a new tab. the function of those plugins disabled..seems they are not loaded..

How to load them when I open a new tab?

Comment: You have a mapping like `nnoremap <D-t> :tabnew<CR>` and do not have similar terminal emulator shortcut? Because if I press `<C-t>` in my yakuake I will open a new yakuake tab, not vim one due to the way yakuake is configured. I do not know a single way to disable functions of plugins just in a new tab, though some plugins (like fugitive) create buffer-local commands and require you to open related files (in case of fugitive - file under git control).

Comment: So, please describe exactly what do you do from starting vim. Not “I run mvim and everything goes fine”, but “I run `mvim railsfile.rb` then type `:SomeAddonCommand<CR>` and it does some thing. Then I press `<D-t>` which shows me a new tab with (empty buffer, current file, shell prompt, whatever) and running `:SomeAddonCommand<CR>` prints `E492: Not a editor command` error”.

Comment: YyX, he is using MacVim, his problem has nothing to do with terminal emulators. But I second your request for more information.

Comment: @Zyx, When I open a file in a RoR folder, for example, 'mvim index.html', some rails-related plugins will automatically loaded, like 'vim-rails'. I can run command ':Rcontroller'..But when I press <C-t> to create a new tab. I cannot run ':Rcontroller' in that tab. But when I checked :pwd, it shows I'm in the right directory, say the RoR directory the same as the first tab.

Comment: @romainl. Check my comment above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these plugins use the similar code to that one fugitive does, then putting something like

```
augroup LaunchFugitiveForAllBuffers
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNew :doautocmd fugitive BufRead .
augroup END
```

(replace `fugitive` with actual event group name [1]). You can find this name by either grepping plugin files for `BufRead` (note: case does not really matter) or walking through the output of `au BufRead` like I did (there should not be many items). Note that things may be more complicated: for example your plugins attach to `Filetype` event and changing the above to `doautocmd fugitive Filetype ruby` may not help. Also note that you can purge out word `fugitive` at all leaving just a space, but it is potentially destructive operation and can be used only for testing (potentially very destructive in case of `Filetype` event and some others).

[1] Note: *event group*, not *plugin* name. These groups are likely to have the name that is a derivative of plugin name, but they are not forced to be equal to it.

**Update**: It seems that you need `railsPluginDetect` group for Tim Pope’s [rails plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails). I do not have any rails project so I can’t say this for sure, but autocommand looks very similar to fugitive one. It is better though that you go to [plugin bug tracker](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/issues) and add a request there (do not forget to search for an existing one).

Answer (score 0):

Additional informations may be needed but I think that's because the new tab creates an empty virtual buffer.

Because your RoR-related plugins only work in a Rails folder and you are not in a Rails folder -- you are probably in `~`, check `:pwd` to know what the working directory is -- those plugins don't work.

Comment: I checked :pwd, the directory was in the same folder, say the Rails folder.But plugins don't work.

Comment: What happens when you write some code and `:saveas newfile.rb`?

Comment: A new file is created in the rails folder..I think maybe I need to load the plugins manually